# How to acquire the EPP code for domains registered at Azure?

Tags: azure, dns, azure-web-app-service

I'd like to transfer my domain from Azure to another registrar. For that I need to

- Unlock the transfer lock
- Get the EPP code AKA transfer code AKA authorization code

How can I do these things?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Login to the Azure portal, select the App Service domain that you wish to transfer out, and click on 'Advanced management' for the domain.

[image]

This will redirect to an external domain management service. (Azure Domains are hosted by Azure DNS, but domain registration is handled by GoDaddy).

[image]

Click on 'Domain Settings' in the menu for the domain you want to transfer.

Under “Additional Settings” you can unlock your domain by clicking on edit for “Domain lock” and turning it Off. You'll then see information about any minimum length of time you need to keep the domain with GoDaddy, or alternatively instructions on how to transfer the domain away from Azure and the codes required.

These instructions are adapted from the [Domain FAQ](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/appserviceteam/2017/08/08/faq-app-service-domain-preview-and-custom-domains/); some of the steps they suggest there are incorrect.